# Printing Unicode output from a subprocess to the terminal on Windows

Tags: python, shell, communication

I'm trying to run a command that emits Unicode output, and print that output to the shell.

My code is similar to the following (`CP850` because that's the codepage used by my Windows terminal, as returned by `chcp`):

```
command = 'echo Тестирование всегда необходимо!'
p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
out = out.decode('CP850')
err = err.decode('CP850')
print(out)
```

I get: `?????????? ?????? ??????????!`

How can I cause the correct text to be passed through?

Comment: Check the examples https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: I can't find anything about Stdin/Stdout or pipes in the Howto.

Comment: CP850 is not Unicode. If you had a terminal (and font) that were Unicode-capable, CP850 wouldn't have any reason to be involved anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to decode this content as if it were in CP850? There is no reason to do so.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct  6 2017, 22:29:07)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> command = "echo 'Тестирование всегда необходимо!'"
>>> p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
>>> out, err = p.communicate()
>>> print out
Тестирование всегда необходимо!
```

---

Similarly, on Python 3:

```
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 29 2018, 15:37:32)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> command = "echo 'Тестирование всегда необходимо!'"
>>> p = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
>>> out, err = p.communicate()
>>> print(out)
Тестирование всегда необходимо!
```

Comment: With the decoding you are right but it does not work me on 3.6

Comment: Python version needs to be specified in the question. And see edit with a Python 3.6 transcript. If you're getting a contrary result, you need to share instructions that others can follow to see it as well.

Comment: I totaly agree, the version is important... It seems to be a problem on Windows 7. I am not able to type these russian characters in the Python Shell as well. When I switch the keyboard layout. All I see are questionsmarks. >>> print('При-вет!')
???-???!

Comment: Does `chcp 65001` help?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is nearly 5 years old, but perhaps this is of use to someone else using subprocess forced to use pipes to capture windows command line output in python.  I've just spent hours Googling how to change subprocess's behaviour, and failing to change the encoding of a text pipe in Windows (I've tried cmd /U and chcp 65001, setting COMSPEC to cmd /U /C &&, and locale to no avail).  I don't know enough about cmd to get furoscame's code working with echo, but I was able to use python -c "print('... ')" as a stand in (which was what I needed to test CLIs).

I found the key was to use Python in the spawned shell, in its utf8 mode.  It's then straightfoward to capture the output as raw bytes instead of text, and decode manually.

```
import subprocess

command = '''python -X utf8 -c "print('Тестирование всегда необходимо!')"'''

result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output = True) 
out = result.stdout.decode('utf8')
err = result.stderr.decode('utf8')

print(f'\n{command=}')
print(f'{out=}')
if err:
    print(f'{err=}')
```

In Windows 10 using python.org's 3.11 installer

```
>python .\tests\so_eg.py 

command='python -X utf8 -c "print(\'Тестирование всегда необходимо!\')"'
out='Тестирование всегда необходимо!\r\n'
```